# Do I need to manually zero out PCREDENTIAL.CredentialBlob?

Tags: c++, winapi, credentials, credential-manager

I'm using the [Windows credentials store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa919793.aspx) like this:

```
PCREDENTIAL cred = nullptr;
if (CredRead(entryName, 1, 0, &cred) != TRUE || !cred)
    return -1;

// ... code which handles cred.UserName and cred.CredentialBlob

CredFree(cred);
```

As you can see I free the buffer as [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credreada). However, I see that the LPBYTE pointer `CredentialBlob` is still valid an still contains the password in memory. Do I have to `SecureZeroMemory` it manually and who owns the buffer? I found no other source code which does that...

I haven't found anything, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa919793.aspx contains just the following generic statement:

> **Clear credential data from memory after use**
>
> Do not leave credentials in memory after use. Clear all credential data from temporary storage after use by calling SecureZeroMemory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You own the buffer.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincred/nf-wincred-credreada) states:

> Any pointers contained within the buffer are pointers to locations within this single allocated block.

In an ideal world, `CredFree` would zero the entire block before freeing it, and it might be worth submitting a suggestion to Microsoft to this effect, but as things stand, your best bet is probably to do the following before calling `CredFree`:

```
SecureZeroMemory (cred->CredentialBlob, cred->CredentialBlobSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

> However, I see that the LPBYTE pointer CredentialBlob is still valid

How do you determine this? Most likely you are committing UB by reading dead memory.

> an still contains the password in memory

This is more concerning but the text you quoted tells you what to do about it.

Comment: I run the debugger and see in the memory view, that the CredentialBlob is not zero'd out(or otherwise feed). That should be done explicitly as it might contain sensitive data.